# Reset the maxlife of a kerberos ticket more than 24h

Tags: kerberos, mit-kerberos

I am using MIT kerberos 5 on my machine to authenticate a user. This grants the ticket to the user. I want to reset the maxlife of a ticket for more than 24 hrs. By default the max life of a kerberos ticket is 24 hrs. I have tried the following steps:

1. Changed the `/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf`
     I did not find max-life so I set `max_life = 168h 0m 0s`
2. Changed the `/etc/krb5.conf`
     Changed the default ticket_lifetime from 24 hrs to
     `ticket_lifetime = 168h 0m 0s`
3. By default the principal lifetime is Maximum ticket life: 1 days 00:00:00
4. I changed it to 168h with the following command

   ```
   kadmin.local:  modify_principal -maxlife 168hours testkerb
   ```
5. It changed to - Maximum ticket life: 7 days 00:00:00
6. Then I did a `kinit` for the user and check with `klist`.

The `klist` result still shows the ticket life as 24 hrs. Output of `klist` is as follows:

```
Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
**11/19/14 12:51:59  11/20/14 12:51:59  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM**
    renew until 11/19/14 12:51:59
```

If someone knows please tell me where am I doing the mistake. Less than 24 hrs I am able to change the ticket life but more than 24 hrs it does not reflect in the `klist`. I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi i got the working step so updating it. To change the max-lifetime of a ticket in kerberos from default 24 hrs to more than 24 hrs follow the following steps:

1. Add the `max_life` property to the `/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf` file.

   ```
   max_life = 168h 0m 0s
   ```
2. Changed the `/etc/krb5.conf` file.

   ```
   ticket_lifetime = 168h 0m 0s
   ```
3. Changed the default principal `krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM` Maximum Life Time.

   ```
   modprinc -maxlife 168hours krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
   ```

Now we can set the ticket life up to 7 days i.e. 168 hrs. We can do `kinit` for user and check the expiry of the ticket by `klist`.

You can also use the `kadmin` command and `getprinc` to see the state of the principal.

```
kadmin:  getprinc krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
Principal: krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
Expiration date: [never]
Last password change: Thu Jan 05 15:23:04 EST 2017
Password expiration date: [none]
Maximum ticket life: 0 days 168:00:00
Maximum renewable life: 7 days 00:00:00
Last modified: Fri Jun 30 08:23:23 EDT 2017 (root/admin@EXAMPLE.COM)
Last successful authentication: Fri Jun 30 08:16:47 EDT 2017
Last failed authentication: [never]
Failed password attempts: 0
Number of keys: 4
Key: vno 3, arcfour-hmac, no salt
Key: vno 3, des3-cbc-sha1, no salt
Key: vno 3, des-cbc-crc, no salt
Key: vno 3, aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, no salt
MKey: vno 1
Attributes: REQUIRES_PRE_AUTH
Policy: [none]
```